# Efficient comparison of two matrices MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix, comparison

Is there a way to efficiently compare two matrices, I was thinking something like

`same = abs((A-B)) = 0...`
 substracting values of one matrix to the other and if they result is 0, they are the same, also there is a `isequal()` function, What would be the best to compare both matrices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that [ISEQUAL](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/isequal.html) is faster than checking for non-zero elements after subtraction:

```
>> a = rand(100, 100);
>> b = a;
>> tic; for ii = 1:100000; any(any(a - b)); end; toc;
Elapsed time is 2.089838 seconds.
>> tic; for ii = 1:100000; isequal(a, b); end; toc;
Elapsed time is 1.201815 seconds.
```

Answer (score 3):

You can simply do `isequal(A,B)` and it will return `1` if true or `0` if false.

Answer (score 3):

Since you're dealing with floating point, you probably don't want to test for exact equality (depending on your application). Thus, you can just check that

```
norm(A - B)
```

is sufficiently small, say `< 1e-9`, again depending on your application. This is the matrix 2-norm, which will be near zero if `A - B` is the all zeros matrix or nearly so.